# Trying to call functions from other classes

Tags: c++, fmod

I'm trying to get `FMOD` working but I just can't get the `main()` to call it

```
int main()
{
  cout << "Using FMOD \n";
  cout << "Select a Track: 1-5 Horror \n";
  cin >> HorrorTrack;

  AudioProject *pAudioProject = new AudioProject;
  pAudioProject->initAudio();
  //AudioProject::initAudio();
  MainPage(); // Main Page Function
  
  if (pAudioProject)
  {
      delete pAudioProject;
      pAudioProject=NULL;
  }
  
  char f;
  cin>>f; 
  return 0;
}
```

The errors I'm getting are:

> unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall AudioProject::AudioProject(void)" (??0AudioProject@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
>
> 1>C:\Users\CodeMonkey\Desktop\AudioProject\Debug\AudioProject.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals.

Which is from the `.h` file variables which are declared `public`. However, if I make the `initAudio` anything but `public` I wont be able to access it in my `main()` function. Any ideas?

Comment: Where are your includes?  Why are there so many asterisks?  It's telling you that it can't find a constructor that takes zero arguments.

Comment: I think he was trying to bold up his markdown, and didn't bother looking at the preview pane. And, no, that's not what the error is saying at all.

Comment: Edit: didn't realize the LNK1120 error below.

Comment: ... That's not what the <<LINKER>> error is saying... It's not a compiler error...

Comment: @JustChris, **no**. It is a _linker_ error. We know that the constructor exists because there is no _compiler_ error, but its _definition_ cannot be found, so there is a build config issue.

Comment: It's a missing symbol error--in this case, the constructor for `AudioProject` is not linked in.

Comment: Yeah you're right it was the constructor in the .cpp I had to fix, the code now runs.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't *linked* the library, so the definitions of symbols that it exports cannot be found.

Read this "FMOD"'s instructions.

Comment: It seems you missed the link to FMOD's instruction documentation.`Read this "FMOD"'s instructions.` No link there.